# Jquery - hide element at specific browser width

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, uinavigationbar, fluid-layout, flexigrid

I am trying to get jQuery to remove an element when the browser eaches a specific width. I am kind of new to jquery. I can workout how to detect the browser width but I cant work out how to say

When browser reaches x width remove unordered list with id y

I have this so far

```
jQuery(function ($) {
                $(window).resize(function(){


                });
        });
```

Help appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The following will work:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  var width = $(this).width(); // The window width
  if (width < someSize) {
    $('#y').hide(); // Or to completely remove it form the DOM use `remove()`
  }
});
```

However, styling is generally best left as the concern of CSS, if you can avoid this approach please try to do so.

Comment: Just to supplement the answer. [Working demo](http://jsbin.com/isosuz/edit#javascript,html).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be doing this with CSS media queries. Trying to do this in Javascript is going to be horribly laggy because of all the resize events that get fired as the window is in the process of being resized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(window).height();` and `$(window).width();` to determine the size.

Answer (score 0):

You know by using CSS media queries you can do this without jQuery?

Check out these resources:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

https://mislav.net/2010/04/targeted-css/

http://protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/mediaqueries/

It can still be done in jQuery by using:

```
    jQuery(function ($) { 
            $(window).resize(function(){ 
                 var _width = $(this).width();
                 if(_width > 900 && $('#myElement').is(':visible'))
                      $('#myElement').hide();
                 else if (_width <= 900  && !$('#myElement').is(':visible'))
                      $('#myElement').show();
            }); 
    });
```

It can also be done as:

```
    jQuery(function ($) { 
            $(window).resize(function(){ 
                 var _width = $(this).width();
                 if(_width > 900)
                      $('#myElement:visible').hide();
                 else if (_width <= 900)
                      $('#myElement:hidden').show();
            }); 
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I know I can do this with media queries but I am trying do do some thing a bit more complicated than usual, also, trying to learn a bit more about jQuery. Thanks, will try some of these solutions.